# Is it a good idea to use UserComments for latest comments in the sidebar?

Tags: schema.org, comments

So, I want to structure the most important parts of the site. I have main page, where there is a grid/wall of thumbnails. On the side, there is latest comments.

Is it a good idea to structure them as `UserComments`? Or will the engines think that those are the comments for that page?

Comment: Google has the ability to detect such elements, look at headers and footers, these are being repeated throughout your site. Your side bar will just be treated as such. Also you could use `<aside>`, then using schema using `itemprop="commentText` and `itemprop="commentUser"`.

Comment: @bybe This sounds like a fine answer to me! I would up-vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Comment](http://schema.org/Comment) instead of [UserComments](http://schema.org/UserComments).

`UserComments` is for the action/event of commenting, while `Comment` represents the published comment itself. (You’ll often find that `UserComments` is used although it’s not appropriate; that is because `Comment` [was introduced later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22341421/1591669).)

---

Neither Schema.org nor Microdata define which conclusions can be drawn when a page contains these annotations, i.e., it is not defined that only the main content should be annotated.

If a consumer (like a search engine) draws a conclusion like "If I find `Comment` markup, I assume that these comments are about the main content of the page", it’s quite adventurous: it would probably be wrong with this conclusion more often than not.

Instead, such a consumer should look for a property relating this `Comment` to *something*. For example, when it finds

[WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) → [comment](http://schema.org/comment) → [Comment](http://schema.org/Comment)

it can conclude that these are comments about the webpage.

When there is no property, the only thing that can be concluded is: There is a comment.

---

So, it’s perfectly fine (and it [can also be useful](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54703/17633)) to mark up *any* content that is shown on the page, not only the main content.