# JSON-LD Schema Data on Multiple Pages

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

Wondering if having identical, verified correct by the Google Structured Data Testing Tool, JSON-LD Schema data on index and the same JSON-LD Schema Data on all subpages would create any sort of problem with google search engine?  Could this be hurting my ranking?

Webmaster Console recognizes pages with it, and is not complaining.

Comment: Just referred to [this link](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82507/should-schema-org-organization-data-about-my-company-be-on-every-page?rq=1). It fully answered my question.