# Should I put structured data for the search box and logo on every page of the site?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, structured-data

Should structured data for the search box and logo only be in the main page of website or should be in all of the pages? and why?

My goal is to use them to get rich snippets in Google.

Comment: I edited your question to correct your terminology.   "Rch snippets" are the enhanced display in the Google search results.  You can't put rich snippets on your pages.  You put structured data into your pages so that Google can display rich snippets for your site in the search results.

Comment: Related: [Should Schema.org Organization data about my company be on every page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82507/should-schema-org-organization-data-about-my-company-be-on-every-page)

Comment: Is your site static HTML or is it built with a CMS like Wordpress?

Comment: @MikeCiffone static HTML.

Comment: @mmdeshoon do you know how to code in PHP?

Comment: @MikeCiffone Yes, why?

Comment: @mmdeshoon So you can create a header.php instead of adding to all pages individually.

Comment: @MikeCiffone I do not have any problem for including the codes in the pages; I want to know the correct way, because for these two Google only show them in results when we search for the name of the websites, but for posts Google not show any logo or search box.

Answer (score 1):

**[Google tells us](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sd-policies)**:

> **Relevance**
>
> Your structured data must be a true representation of the
> page content.
>
> **Location**
>
> Put the structured data on the page that it
> describes, unless specified otherwise by the documentation.

Thus, you can easily set the markup for the search box and logo on all pages that have a search box and a logo in the main (visible to users) content.

Comment: So why does Google show the logo and search box only for the main page of the website? like pinterest website on Google search results.

Comment: There may be many reasons - read more https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sd-policies